# Using in a derived class a specific overloaded function from base

Tags: c++

I want to use just a specific function, not all overloads, form a derived class. Can I do this in some way with the **using** keyword?

Let's say we have:

```
class A
{
public:
    void f(int i);
private:
    void f(float i);
};

class B : A
{
public:
    void f(int i) { A::f(i); }
};

class C : A
{
public:
    using A::f;
};
```

This code fails with `void f(float i)` being private in `A`.

As you can see, it is possible to just wrap the function as is show in `B`. Is it possible to write, that I am `using` just `void f(int i)` in `C` and not `void f(float i)` as well?

Comment: 1. Bang your head against the desk. 2. Repeat. 3. Think of a better design

Comment: You already hide the `void f(float i)` very well. Any attempt to call it in `class C` will fail. Why do you need the `using` statement?

Comment: @gdlmx - I suspect that the question is "can this be done", not "I want to do this, how can I get it to work".

Comment: I made a clarification in the question. I also suspect it is not possible to do this with 'using', but I am not that well-versed in that corner of C++ to be sure.